# How check that string is NOT blank by java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

There is regular expression for [finding blank string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012788/how-to-check-if-a-line-is-blank-using-regex) and I want only negation. I also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967075/regex-for-not-empty-and-not-whitespace) but it does not work for java (see examples). [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448829/regular-expression-for-not-empty) also not work for me (see 3-rd line in example).

For example

```
Pattern.compile("/^$|\\s+/").matcher(" ").matches() - false
Pattern.compile("/^$|\\s+/").matcher(" a").matches()- false
Pattern.compile("^(?=\\s*\\S).*$").matcher("\t\n a").matches() - false
```

return false in both cases.

**P.S.** If something is not clear ask me questions.

**UPDATED**

I want to use this regular expression in [@Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation without creating custom annotation and programmatic validator for it. That's why I want a "plain" regexp solution without using [find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) function.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you mean by negation.

If you mean "a string that contains at least one non-blank character," then you can use this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\S").matcher(str).find()
```

If it's really necessary to use `matches`, then you can do it with this.

```
Pattern.compile("\\A\\s*\\S.*\\Z").matcher(str).matches()
```

This just matches 0 or more spaces followed by a non-space followed by any characters at all up to the end of the string.

If you mean "a string that is all non-blank with at least one such character," then you can use this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\A\\S+\\Z").matcher(str).matches()
```

You need to study the [Java regex syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html).  In Java, regular expressions are compiled from strings, so there's no need for special delimiters like `/.../` or `%r{...}` as you'll see in other languages.

Comment: Congratulations to your 10k!

Comment: Pattern.compile("\\S").matcher("abc").matches() - false, but must be true.
Your solution is only for 1 character in the string.

Comment: @Cherry Use `find` instead of `match`.  I edited the answer to make this explicit.

Comment: @Cherry Then what do you mean by negation?  The opposite of a string of all spaces is a string that is not all spaces, which is a string that contains at least one non-space.  That's what I gave you the regex for...

Comment: The main reason why I added this question is possibility to use [@Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) to ckeck that input string is not blank. So I do not want to use find() function. I can create my own annotation and write a validator, but I asked to check is there solution in "plain" rexexp or not.

Comment: @Cherry Of course it doesn't.  As my answer says, this finds all strings that consist of all _non-blank_ characters, where there is at least one of these.

Comment: @Cherry Ok I added a regex that uses `matches` to match a line with at least one non-blank in it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if(!string.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If string is null, throws [`java.lang.NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: Updated question description.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` `\s` : A whitespace character:  `\t\n\x0B\f\r`.

```
Pattern.compile("\\s")
```

Comment: Works only for string with 1 character.